# how to deploy puppet master and puppet agent with juju?

Tags: juju, puppet, puppetmaster

I've an ubuntu 14.04lts server with MaaS and Juju, and both of them are installed via ppa stable.
I'd like to deploy puppet master on a Juju node and puppet agent on the other node present on my virtual environment. 
I've tried to find that on juju charms but is not present for trusty. 
thats for support

Comment: anyone can help me?

Comment: I'll ask someone to push those to trusty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's interesting to hear more about what you're trying to achieve, because both Juju and Puppet are orchestration tools, and they cannot *both* manage the same machines as they will most likely interfere with each other. You can install puppet master and install the puppet agents on some other machines, not managed by juju, or you can use puppet scripts/commands inside a juju charm to do some other work. But most likely deploying both puppet master and puppet agent in the same juju environment seems unnecessary.